# Spiting Regular expression and accessing Array of Array

Tags: regex, powershell

**An example am trying to understand from website.
People2.txt is as follows.**

2323:Doe John California

827:Doe Jane Texas

982982:Neuman Alfred Nebraska

**I don't get the output as shown from the command below**.

*PS C:\ Get-Content people2.txt | %{$data = [regex]::split($_, '\t|:'); Write-Output "$($data[2]) $($data[1]), $($data[3])"}

John Doe, California

Jane Doe, Texas

Alfred Neuman, Nebraska*

**I could take out numbers and swapping first and second using**

gc C:\appl\ppl.txt | %{$data = [regex]::split($_, ":") ;write-output $data[1] } | Out-File c:\appl\ppll.txt

gc C:\appl\ppll.txt | %{$data = $_.split(" "); Write-Output "$($data[1]) $($data[0]), 
$($data[2])"}

**Please help**

**Need to find more efficient ways to do this.

Also  I want to understand '\t|:' - is it 'Split at first TAB stop and a : ' ?**

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? how would you like to have your output?

Comment: What is the significance of $($data) enclosing a variable inside a variable ?

Comment: Output should be like                                                                                                                                    John Doe, California
Jane Doe, Texas
Alfred Neuman, Nebraska*

Answer (score 0):

Just threw this off the top of my head: `^(?<number>\d+):(?<first>\w+)\s+(?<last>\w+)\s(?<location>.*)$`